# binary to int with strtol in C

Tags: c

I'm extracting 8 bytes from a big-endian binary file to decode into actual readable information, the second nibble from byte 4, byte 5 and byte 6 need to be concatenated and printed as a long integer value:

example input data (in binary): 0000 0000 0101 0110 1111 1000 0101 0101 0000 **0001 0011 1010 0101 0000** 0000 0110

example input data (hex representation): 0x0056f8550**13a50**06

In bold are the bits i'm intending to print as long integer.

expected output: 80464

I tried the following but the result of strtol is always 0, I tried using base 0,2,10,16 always result 0.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
unsigned char fromfile[8];  //contains 8 bytes from a binary file
unsigned long int output;   //output to be printed

unsigned char numbers[4];
numbers[0] = fromfile[4]&0x0f;
numbers[1] = fromfile[5];
numbers[2] = fromfile[6];
numbers[3] = '\0';

output=strtol (numbers,NULL,2);
printf("%lu",output);

return 0;
}
```

To elaborate fromfile array contains the following:

```
fromfile[0]=0x00;
fromfile[1]=0x56;
fromfile[2]=0xf8;
fromfile[3]=0x55;
fromfile[4]=0x01;
fromfile[5]=0x3a;
fromfile[6]=0x50;
fromfile[7]=0x06;
```

Compiling this code using the gcc compiler on a centos virtual machine.

Comment: Did you read `strtol` manual? It converts **string** to integer.

Comment: "extracting 8 bytes from a binary file" sounds like you have 64 bit value. Is it binary or it is 8 ASCII digits?

Comment: It sounds like you already have binary data, and then try to convert it to binary data.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a sample input and output, it's not clear what procedure you are describing

Comment: Don't pass an *unterminated* char array to `strtol`.

Comment: You still are trying to use `strtol` on something *that is not a string*. It seems you don't get that part yet.

Comment: @Jongware I understand that what I sent to `strtol` is not a string and doesn't work the way I did it, but I don't know if there is a way to convert my input to a string first to be able to use `strtol` on it.

Comment: That sounds like an entirely different question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the input byte order is big-endian, you can do this:

```
unsigned char fromfile[8];  //contains 8 bytes from a binary file
unsigned long int output;   //output to be printed

output =
  (fromfile[4] & 0xf) << 16 |
  fromfile[5] << 8 |
  fromfile[6];

printf("%lu", output);
```

To explain what's happening in the expression assigned to `output`, let's look at bytes 4 through 6 of the input which correspond to the binary digits 23 through 0 of the desired value (because of the big endian byte order):

```
byte:         4        5        6
 bit: 23       15        7      0
       00001111 11111111 11111111
```

We're interested in the bits masked with `1` and not interested in bits masked with `0`.

1. `fromfile[4] & 0xf` takes byte 4 and masks its value with F<sub>16</sub> = 00001111<sub>2</sub>, which is exactly the mask underneath byte 4 in the figure above,  using the bitwise AND operation (`&`).
2. `... << 16` shifts the result of step 1 to the left by 16 binary digit positions, which is exactly the position where we need the lower nibble of byte 4 to go according to the figure above.
3. `fromfile[5] << 8` – similarly to step 2, this takes byte 5 and shifts it to the left by 5 positions because that's where its bits are supposed to go.
4. `fromfile[6]` doesn't perform a bit shift, because the value read from byte 6 needs to be mapped to the lowest 8 bits of the output value anyway.
5. So now we have three values (`X`, `Y`, and `Z` mark unknown bits of the values `x`, `y`, and `z` respectively):

   ```
   0000XXXX 00000000 00000000
   00000000 YYYYYYYY 00000000
   00000000 00000000 ZZZZZZZZ
   ```

   To assemble them into one value, we use the binary OR operation (`|`) twice (`x | y | z`):

   ```
   0000XXXX YYYYYYYY ZZZZZZZZ
   ```

   This is exactly how we want the bits of the input data arranged and we're done.

Comment: Thank you ! the second one for big-endian worked for me, could you please explain to me what you did there? It seems I have completely misunderstood the problem.

Comment: Alright, I'll extend my question accordingly. Please refine your question accordingly: clarify the endianness of the input data and the target architecture(s) and give one or more example pairs for input and expected output.